# C# background worker sql

Tags: c#, database, multithreading, backgroundworker

I want to load a method which sets a number from database to a textfield using  a backgroundworker method...I tried days to find a way but still couldn't. When I call this method inside DoWork method nothing happens.

This is the method;

```
        Int32 id = 0;

        string query = "SELECT MAX( CONVERT( SUBSTRING(RefNo, 3) , UNSIGNED INTEGER) ) FROM has.recruitments";
        MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdda = new MySqlCommand(query, conDatabase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {
            conDatabase.Open();

            myReader = cmdda.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                id = myReader.GetInt32(0);
            }


            if (!(Application.OpenForms.OfType<Report>().Any()))
            {
                // MessageBox.Show("Opened");

                int id1 = id + 1;
                String s = "MP0" + id1;

                //  MessageBox.Show(s);
                textBox5.Text = s;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: How do you know it runs at all?

Comment: "nothing happens" is not a good description of your problem. Please, describe more precisely - what's going wrong? Are you getting some exception?

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Comment: You better use `ExecuteScalar` if u only need one value. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Nothing happens ? I would expect a exception because you try to manipulate a control(of the GUI thread) from the backgroundworker(a thread that is not able to manipulate the GUI without some tricks). If that is the case you need to give back a result and manipulate the GUI in the backgroundworker_runworkercompleted event or to work with a delegate you invoke from inside the backgroundworker-dowork event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not update the GUI from a background thread. This has been discussed here so many times it shouldn't be worth mentioning, actually.

The thing is, you (like many other people) use the background worker wrong. Ideally, all the work you do in `DoWork` should not depend on the UI (and in your case it doesn't really). You should return a result that you evaluate in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event.

If you really need to do progress updates from a background worker which go beyond a "finished x% of the work", you need to invoke these updates in the context of the UI thread.

In your case, the background worker is meant to keep the UI responsive while performing a database query. So what you should do is:

1. In `DoWork`, perform the query *only*
2. From `DoWork`,  return a result that contains the value queried or error information
3. Evaluate that result in `RunWorkerCompleted`
4. Remove any UI-dependent code from `DoWork`